# Убрать пробелы в строке СИ

Tags: c

Программа выдает в начале и в конце строки s мусорные символы, которых нет в строке строке с. Как это можно пофиксить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    char input[SIZE], s[SIZE];
    int len = 0, i= 0, j = 0;
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &input);
    len = strlen(input);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] != ' ')
        {
            j++;
            s[j] = input[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на _StackOverflow._  Пожалуйста, не забывайте голосовать и отмечать верные ответы, нажимая на галочку под числом голосов.  См. [раздел помощи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не было мусора в начале нужно переставить

```
s[j] = input[i];

j++;
```

иначе вы пишете с номера 1

А для избавления от мусора в конце следует после цикла добавить символ конца строки ( он не посчитан len'ом

```
s[j] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы инкрементируете `j` *перед* тем, как записать
в строку, и не выставляете последний байт в `'\0'`.
Попробуйте как-то так:

```c
char user_input[STRSIZE];
char *fg_res = fgets(user_input, STRSIZE, stdin);
if (fg_res == NULL) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read /dev/stdin: eof\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "read /dev/stdin: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 2;
}

char result[STRSIZE];
size_t n = strlen(user_input);
size_t j = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (user_input[i] != ' ') {
        result[j] = user_input[i];
        j++;
    }
}
result[j] = '\0';
```